# How is nullptr rvalue

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, rvalue, nullptr

While looking at the implementation of `nullptr` [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf), what got my attention is that `nullptr` is `rvalue` which means we can do something like this

```
std::nullptr_t&& nullref = nullptr;
```

But how could `nullptr` be `rvalue` since the implementations is something like this

```
const class {...} nullptr = {};
```

Is this core feature ? What am I missing ?

Comment: _Every_ keyword is a "core feature".

Comment: It's just like `this`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Implementation has nothing to do with it.

The keyword `nullptr` is defined to produce an rvalue expression, and that's the end of it.

> `[C++14: 2.14.7/1]`: The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. *[ Note:* `std::nullptr_t` is a distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value. See 4.10 and 4.11. *—end note ]*

I agree you couldn't yourself reimplement it to this criterion in userspace, but then that's the case for every single other keyword also.

Expressions consisting only of the keywords `true` and `false` are also rvalues, if you're curious.

> `[C++14: 2.14.6/1]:` The Boolean literals are the keywords `false` and `true`. Such literals are prvalues and have type `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

If Alternative #1 were the definition of `nullptr`, then you are right that it would be an lvalue. However, it could be forced to be an rvalue using something like this:

```
const class __nullptr_t {...} __nullptr = {};
#define nullptr (__nullptr_t(__nullptr));
```

That's not what was ultimately standardized though. In actual C++11, `nullptr` is a literal, the same way as `3.14` or `'x'`.